# How do I preselect CheckboxList and being able to check and unchecking after reading the results back from sql db in C#

Tags: c#, checkboxlist

I am newb here and building a db for keeping track of my movies (for practice). Anyway, I'm using a checkboxlist to enter the genre (action, comedy, drama, horror, etc..). I got the checkboxlist to save back to the db table and I was able to get the saved results to preload the checkboxlist BUT my problem is to be able to uncheck and check new genre and save back to the db.

here is my code to check the items in the GenreCheckBox list and save to the db table.

```
for (int i = 0; i < GenreCheckBoxList.Items.Count; i++)
    {

        if (GenreCheckBoxList.Items[i].Selected)
        {
            cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("MovieID", MovieID);
            cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GenreID", GenreCheckBoxList.Items[i].Value);
            cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("Status", Status);
            cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
            cmd2.Parameters.Clear();
        }

    }
```

Here is my method to show the previously saved GenreCheckBoxList results

```
public void LoadGenreCheckBoxList()
        {
            GenreCheckBoxList.DataBind();

            string MovieID = Session["MovieID"].ToString();

            SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=STEVE-F32A48EEB;Initial Catalog=Sinema;Integrated Security=True");
            cnn.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("SELECT Genre.GenreType, Genre.GenreID, GenreLine.GenreID FROM Genre INNER JOIN GenreLine ON Genre.GenreID = GenreLine.GenreID INNER JOIN Movie ON GenreLine.MovieID = Movie.MovieID WHERE GenreLine.MovieID = @MovieID AND GenreLine.Status = 1", cnn);

            cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MovieID", MovieID);
            cmd2.ExecuteScalar();


            SqlDataReader rdr2 = cmd2.ExecuteReader();
            while (rdr2.Read())
            {
                ListItem currentCheckBox = GenreCheckBoxList.Items.FindByValue(rdr2["GenreID"].ToString());

                if (currentCheckBox != null)
                {
                    currentCheckBox.Selected = true;
                }
            }


            rdr2.Close();
        }
```

Now what I want to do is after the results are showing on my edit page, I would like to be able to uncheck some of the checks or check some new genre and not have the already selected checked genre's to duplicate and save back to the db.

I dont even know where to start. Any direction would help greatly!  How do I write if statements to meet the condition of if the genreCheckBoxList is already checked then dont save back to the db and if it isnt already checked save back to the db? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have two options for you.

**Answer 1**

As per the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.togglebutton.isthreestate%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), you can turn the checkbox into a three-state checkbox.  On load, you'd do this for any checkbox which was checked based on the database, and you'd toggle between three states: "Save unchecked", "Don't save either way" (i.e. leave the database how it was), and "Save checked".  The remaining checkboxes would just have the one state.

```
checkBox1.IsThreeState = true;
checkBox1.IsChecked = null;
```

**Answer 2**

Store the original state of each checkbox in its `Tag` attribute.  When you save back to the database, check to see whether `(bool)checkBox1.Tag == checkBox1.IsChecked`.  If so, skip it.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I'm using web applications with the namespace system.data.sqlclient.

Comment: Does a CheckBoxList have a tag attribute? I never utilized this method before, could you explain a bit further please?

Comment: @user1726200 - Every WinForm control has a Tag.  I'm not entirely sure about web controls, though.  I didn't realize that was what you were building on.  Nothing in this answer will be relevant to you.

Comment: @user1726200 - If you post your current (duplicating) save code, I can try to help with that.